# How to expand a div and insert new text without distorting other objects in that div?

Tags: html, css

## The problem

I am trying to create a box that can expand with an icon an text inside of it. I want the icon to be always visible and not move and the to pop in the bow when hovering over it. However when I load in the text it messes up the layout of the icon. See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5bjbsgg/).

It would be best if the icon could stay in place without moving at all. How can I best achieve this?

Here is the code:

```css
.box {
  width: 60px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #96ffd1;
}

.box:hover {
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.box>i {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
  height: 36px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.box:hover span {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class='box'>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
  <span>Display when expanded</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Attach fiddle link properly please.

Comment: Use `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line-height` = `height` of icon. *(To center the icon)*

`padding-left` equal to width of icon.

```css
.box {
  width: 60px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #96ffd1;
}

.box:hover {
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.box>i {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 36px;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
  height: 36px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.box:hover span {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class='box'>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
  <span>Display when expanded</span>
</div>
```